# IOCP ReadFile always blocks until read completion

Tags: readfile, iocp

This is an example source for reading files using iocp.

It should be returned immediately because it makes an asynchronous call when calling ReadFile, which seems to work synchronously.

What is the problem?

he test environment is visual studio 2017 enterprise, windwos 10,
The windows sdk version is 10.0.17763.0.

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)

const int BUFFERSIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 400;
BYTE ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = { 0 };

DWORD WINAPI WaitQueue(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    auto hIocp = (HANDLE)lpParam;

    // WAIT COMPLETION QUEUE
    DWORD numberOfBytes;
    ULONG_PTR val;

    LPOVERLAPPED ov = { 0 };

    for (;;)
    {
        BOOL bSuccess = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIocp, &numberOfBytes, (PULONG_PTR)&val, &ov, INFINITE);

        SYSTEMTIME dequeTime;
        GetSystemTime(&dequeTime);

        Sleep(1000);

        printf("dequeue time %dsec %dmilli", dequeTime.wSecond, dequeTime.wMilliseconds);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ReadFileThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    Sleep(3000);

    auto hIocp = (HANDLE)lpParam;

    // CREATE FILE HANDLE
    auto fileName = "e:\\test.msi";

    auto hFile = CreateFile(fileName,
        FILE_READ_DATA,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::wcout << L"create file fail - " << fileName << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // REGIST FILE HANDLE TO IOCP
    if (hIocp != CreateIoCompletionPort(hFile, hIocp, 0, 2))
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();

        std::cout << "add file handle fail:" << err << " - file handle:" << hIocp << std::endl;

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hIocp);
        return 0;
    }

    // READ FILE
    OVERLAPPED ol = { 0 };

    SYSTEMTIME startTime;
    GetSystemTime(&startTime);

    if (FALSE == ReadFile(hFile, ReadBuffer, _countof(ReadBuffer), 0, &ol))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            printf("Terminal failure: Unable to read from file.\n GetLastError=%08x\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    DWORD d;
    GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ol, &d, true);

    SYSTEMTIME endTime;
    GetSystemTime(&endTime);

    printf("start time %dsec %dmilli", startTime.wSecond, startTime.wMilliseconds);
    printf("end time %dsec %dmilli", endTime.wSecond, endTime.wMilliseconds);
}

int main()
{
    // CREATE ICOP
    auto hIocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 1);

    if (hIocp == NULL)
    {
        auto err = GetLastError();

        std::cout << "Create IOCP failed. error:" << err << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // CREATE READ THREAD
    CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        ReadFileThread,
        hIocp,
        0,
        nullptr
    );

    // CREATE WAIT DEQUEUE THREAD
    CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        WaitQueue,
        hIocp,
        0,
        nullptr
    );

    while (true)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what you try prove with this code ? you even not do main by logic in your code - not check time when `ReadFile` return. this is must be end time, not after you wait in `GetOverlappedResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the *iocp* here is absolute unrelated. you try check are I/O operation (read in your case) on asynchronous file handle return immediately or block. how is *iocp* here related ? bind *iocp* to file is only way get notification, when I/O is complete. but this is absolute not affect are I/O byself block or return immediately. we can use any notification way here. (apc, iocp or event). for your test purpose the most simply use event.

then let look like - how you test - are read block or return in your code ? you not test this at all. test this need after `ReadFile` return - are operation completed or not. the I/O operation (ReadFile) is completed asynchronous - if api call already return control to you, but `OVERLAPPED`(`IO_STATUS_BLOCK` ) yet not updated by system, which mean that I/O still not completed. are `OVERLAPPED` updated we can check direct (`Internal` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure is **not** `STATUS_PENDING`) or by call [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresult) with *bWait* set to *FALSE*

> If this parameter is `FALSE` and the operation is still pending, the
>   function returns `FALSE` and the `GetLastError` function returns
>   `ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE`.

so we can say that `ReadFile` completed asynchronously if next 4 codition is true:

1. `ReadFile` return `FALSE`
2. `GetLastError()` return `ERROR_IO_PENDING`
3. `GetOverlappedResult(.., FALSE)` return `FALSE`
4. `GetLastError()` return `ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE`

you not check this in self code. instead you wait until io operation is full complete via `GetOverlappedResult(.., true)` and take time of this. and what sense do this ?

real code for test:

```
void tt(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        OVERLAPPED ov {};
        if (ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            char buf[1024];
            if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, &ov))
            {
                DbgPrint("sync(#1)\n");
            }
            else
            {
                switch (GetLastError())
                {
                case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                    ULONG n;
                    if (GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &n, FALSE))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("sync(#2)\n");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        switch (GetLastError())
                        {
                        case ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE:
                            DbgPrint("async\n");
                            if (!GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &n, TRUE))
                            {
                                __debugbreak();
                            }
                            break;
                        default: __debugbreak();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default: __debugbreak();
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

note that result (synchronous or not) complete of read depend from are file data in cache. if you call it for file, which was not readed before (so data not in cache) possible api print "async", but if you call this function again for the same file - you next time faster of all (almost 100%) will view "sync(#2)"